# Flux.range waits to emit more element once 256 elements are reached

Tags: java, project-reactor, flux

I wrote this code:

```java
Flux.range(0, 300)
            .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("i = " + i))
            .flatMap(i -> Mono.just(i)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
                            .delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
            )
            .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("end " + i))
            .blockLast();
```

When running it, the first `System.out.println` shows that the Flux stop emitting numbers at the 256th element, then it waits for the older to be completed before emitting new ones.

Why is this happening?
Why 256?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why this happening?

The `flatMap` operator can be characterized as operator that (rephrased from javadoc):

1. subscribes to its inners *eagerly*
2. does not preserve ordering of elements.
3. lets values from different inners interleave.

For this question the **first** point is important. Project Reactor restricts the
number of in-flight *inner* sequences via `concurrency` parameter.

While [`flatMap(mapper)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) uses the default parameter the [`flatMap(mapper, concurrency)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-int-) overload accepts this parameter explicitly.

The [`flatMap`s](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-int-) javadoc describes the parameter as:

> The concurrency argument allows to control how many Publisher can be subscribed to and merged in parallel

Consider the following code using `concurrency` = `500`

```java
Flux.range(0, 300)
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("i = " + i))
        .flatMap(i -> Mono.just(i)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
                        .delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(1000)),
                500
//         ^^^^^^^^^^
        )
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("end " + i))
        .blockLast();
```

In this case there is no waiting:

```sh
i = 297
i = 298
i = 299
end 0
end 1
end 2
```

In contrast if you pass **`1` as `concurrency`** the output will be similar to:

```
i = 0
end 0
i = 1
end 1
```

Awaiting one second before emitting the next element.

#### Why 256?

256 is the *default* value for concurrency of `flatMap`.

Take a look at [`Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE`](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/f861fb8ce2862ffe4bc58e2696418a90427bf5c2/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/util/concurrent/Queues.java#L88):

```java
public static final int SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE = Math.max(16,
        Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("reactor.bufferSize.small", "256")));
```